# Item in qTableWidget won't update after a "return" key pressed

Tags: pyqt4, cell, updates, qtablewidget

I have an already filled qTableWidget and I would like to change the content of one cell. 
So I double-click on this cell, the previous text become highlighted, I enter a new text and I hit the "return" key.
I catch the "key pressed" signal and the connected slot contains a function that prints the content of the modified cell.

```py
# Override qTableWidget class to catch event
class MyQTableWidget(PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
         super(MyQTableWidget, self).keyPressEvent(event)
         key = event.key()

         if key == PyQt4.QtCore.Qt.Key_Return or key == PyQt4.QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
             self.emit(PyQt4.QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed"))

...

# Connect the "keypress" signal
self.tableWidget_casesList.connect(self.tableWidget_casesList, PyQt4.QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed"), self.renameCase)

...

# Print the modified text of the cell
def renameCase(self):
    # Get the new text entered by user 
    newCaseName = str(self.tableWidget_casesList.item(self.tableWidget_casesList.currentRow(), 1).text())
    print("New case's name : {0:s}".format(newCaseName))
```

Pb : The printed text is the original one, not the modified one. I have to hit the "return" key again to get the new text printed…
Is there a specific action to do to force the update of the qTableWidget before executing the slot function ?

Comment: Call the base-class `keyPressEvent` first (and not in an `else` branch).

Comment: I have made the modifications you have suggested (previous post edited) but it still doesn't work...

Comment: It does work - it just doesn't do what you expected it to. I suggest you use [one of the signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#signals) that has been designed for the purpose instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I see your point. 
As you have suggested, I have used an existing signal (`cellChanged`) and it works just as I expect it.

```py
    self.tableWidget_casesList.connect(self.tableWidget_casesList, PyQt4.QtCore.SIGNAL("cellChanged(int,int)"), self.renameCase)

    ...

    def renameCase(self, row, col):

        if col == 1:    
            # Get the new text entered by user 
            newCaseName = str(self.tableWidget_casesList.item(row, 1).text())
            print("New case's name : {0:s}".format(newCaseName))
```

I have added a test on the column value in order to apply this signal on all rows of the first column only...

Thanks for your help ekhumoro !